# ViewModel with 3 variables depending on each others and update UI on Android

Tags: android

I am making a sample app and I found something I do not understand how to tackle.
I have a `ViewModel` containing 3 variables.
1 of them is the result of an operation, so it depends on the others:

```
    private val _a = MutableLiveData<Int>().apply {
        value = 0
    }
    val a: LiveData<Int> = _a

    private val _b = MutableLiveData<Int>().apply {
        value = 0
    }
    val b: LiveData<Int> = _b

    private val _c = MutableLiveData<Int>().apply {
        value = 100
    }
    val c: LiveData<Int> = _c

    fun updateA(value: Int) {
        val cvalue = 100 - _a.value!! - _b.value!!

        _a.postValue(value)
        _c.postValue(cvalue)
    }
```

What happens is that the numbers shown on UI (using `observe(viewLifecycleOwner)` etc...) are wrong: there is always a different by 1 or similar.

The UI has 2 `SeekBar` for `a` and `b` and 3 `TextView`s showing the values of `a`, `b` and `c`.
At the moment, I added a *change listener* only to `a` and it calls `updateA` passing `progress` as parameter.
So at the moment `b` is always `0`. What happens is that when `a` becomes `2` (because I move the `SeekBar` handle to that position), the value of `c` is not `98`, but `99` so the sum is `101` instead of `100`.

I was thinking it could depends on how threads decide to update those values when I call `postValue`, but I didn't find anything in the documentation.
I tested another approach that is to calculate all values when the widget calls the *change listener* and it works perfectly, but I assume that should not the right approach...
Can someone give me some advice?
Regards

Comment: Can you add some specific details? What calls do you make to this sample ViewModel (and who calls that update method) what values are shown, and what values do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some info missing to give you a complete answer but you can just declare the third LiveData as a transformation from the other two and to do this you usually use a `MediatorLiveData` which mediates the values between many sources.

```kotlin
class YourViewModel : ViewModel() {
  
  // Assuming a and b to be what you've declared

  val c: LiveData<Int> = MediatorLiveData().apply {
    addSource(a) { mostRecentA ->
      value = yourOperation(mostRecentA, b.value) // or default value
    }
    addSource(b) { mostRecentB ->
      value = yourOperation(a.value, mostRecentB) // or default value
    }
  }

  // If these functions are called from the main thread 
  // it's safe to just assign the value
  fun setA(value: Int) { _a.value = value }
  fun setB(value: Int) { _b.value = value }

  fun yourOperation(aVal: Int?, bVal: Int?) = 100 - (aVal?:0) - (bVal?:0)
}
```